# Systemd socket activation proxy?

Tags: systemd, socket-activation

I have systemd setup, and it runs:

- nginx.service on `:80`
- wikiname.socket `:8080`
- wikiname.service `:9094`

So here is what I do...

1. I check if wikiname.service is running...and it is not.
2. I start the wikiname.socket unit.
3. I visit http://wikiserver:8080/ my browser does nothing...
4. I check again to see if wikiname.service is running and now it is, it was started by my browser activating the socket!

This is great and all but...

How can I have the wikiname.socket on the same socket as wikiname.service?

P.S. Before I found out about socket activation in systemd, I was starting the wikiname.service process manually and then when the correct path was called on nginx `:80` the request would be proxied to the `wikiname.service`, but I'd rather use socket activation, so how do I keep both the `wikiname.socket` and `wikiname.service` on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the whole idea is that wiki name.socket and wiki name.service should be on the *same* socket, i.e. both on 8080.

This probably requires that wikiname.service is modified to support socket activation though, check [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) for examples.